# Combining `drop` and `create as select` with cte syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql

-- Temp table with variables that can be changed
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_vars;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_vars AS
SELECT
TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-10-01 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') AS startDateTime,
TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-10-14 23:59:59.999', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') AS endDateTime,
'Sackey' AS tenantName, -- only one tenant name
ARRAY['Bright'] AS groupNameArray,
'week' AS groupBy; -- one of 'day', 'week', 'month', 'year'

-- Create a Common Table Expression (CTE) for tmp_vars_median_response
WITH tmp AS (
SELECT *
FROM tmp_vars_median
)
-- Create temporary table for median first expert response
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_first_response;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_first_response AS
SELECT
CASE
WHEN mm.groupBy = 'day' THEN mm.created
WHEN mm.groupBy = 'week' THEN EXTRACT('WEEK' FROM mm.created)
WHEN mm.groupBy = 'month' THEN EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM mm.created)
ELSE EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM mm.created)
END AS "day_week_month_year",
CAST(AVG(mm.expert_response_time)/1000 AS DECIMAL(10,0)) AS first_expert_response_secs_median_avg_resolved
FROM
(
SELECT
m.created,
m.expert_response_time,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
CASE
WHEN tmp.groupBy = 'day' THEN m.created::varchar
WHEN tmp.groupBy = 'week' THEN EXTRACT('WEEK' FROM m.created)::varchar
WHEN tmp.groupBy = 'month' THEN EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM m.created)::varchar
ELSE EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM m.created)::varchar
END
ORDER BY m.expert_response_time
) rn,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY
CASE
WHEN tmp.groupBy = 'day' THEN m.created::varchar
WHEN tmp.groupBy = 'week' THEN EXTRACT('WEEK' FROM m.created)::varchar
WHEN tmp.groupBy = 'month' THEN EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM m.created)::varchar
ELSE EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM m.created)::varchar
END
) cnt,
tmp.groupBy
FROM
message m
JOIN
tmp
ON
m.tenant_name = tmp.tenantName
AND m.group_name = ANY(tmp.groupNameArray)
AND m.created >= tmp.startDateTime
AND m.created <= tmp.endDateTime
AND m.lifecycle_state = 'resolved'
AND m.expert_response_time IS NOT NULL
) AS mm
WHERE
rn IN (FLOOR((cnt + 1)/2), FLOOR((cnt + 2)/2))
GROUP BY
CASE
WHEN mm.groupBy = 'day' THEN mm.created
WHEN mm.groupBy = 'week' THEN EXTRACT('WEEK' FROM mm.created)
WHEN mm.groupBy = 'month' THEN EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM mm.created)
ELSE EXTRACT('YEAR' FROM mm.created)
END;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I keep on getting this error when I run this ERROR: syntax error at or near "DROP"LINE 9: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp\_first\_response\_median](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563877/i-keep-on-getting-this-error-when-i-run-this-error-syntax-error-at-or-near-dro)

Comment: @Jens the newer copy got taken down, you can retract the vote

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange not just your `drop`, but also the `with` and `create`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HUbjqsM-)

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS
WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tmp_response
)
SELECT ...
```

Once you've done that, you'll also need to fix the first `case` because `created` must be a timestamp for `extract()` to work with it, and [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) yields a numeric, so you end up mixing `case` return types.

Also, you probably want [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), not `extract()`:

```sql
select sample.ts,
       extract(day from sample.ts) extract_day,
       date_trunc('day',sample.ts) date_trunc_day,
       extract(week from sample.ts) extract_week,
       date_trunc('week',sample.ts) date_trunc_week,
       extract(month from sample.ts) extract_month,
       date_trunc('month',sample.ts) date_trunc_month
from (values ('now'::timestamp)) as sample(ts);
```

| ts | extract_day | date_trunc_day | extract_week | date_trunc_week | extract_month | date_trunc_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-28 13:13:45.821576 | 28 | 2023-11-28 00:00:00 | 48 | 2023-11-27 00:00:00 | 11 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00 |